# Evaluation of vector field integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization

I have a task at hand where I am to solve the integral of a conservative vector field F along a path that is the unit circle centered at origin, oriented CCW.

$${\bf F}(x,y) = (-\frac y{x^2+y^2}){\bf i} + (\frac x{x^2+y^2}){\bf j}$$

I have attempted to integrate both of the terms here to find the potential function, that proved to be difficult.

I have however 2 questions regarding this integral.

1. Given this follows a path that is the unit circle, does that not mean that the integral would evaluate to 0 as the integral is path independent and both starts and terminates at the same point?
2. Evaluating this integral by parameterizing the path yields 2pi as the answer:

$$\int_K{\bf \vec F(\vec r(t))}{\cdot}r´(t)\cdot{\rm d}{\bf t}$$

$$ r(t) = cos(t){\bf i} + sin(t){\bf j}$$
$$ r´(t) = -sin(t){\bf i} + cos(t){\bf j}$$

Would the answer be 2pi, 0 or something else that I have missed?

Comment: 1) Only if $F$ is defined on the entire disk-shaped area you want to contract the path through.  This $F$ is not defined at $(0,0)$ and this "puncture" obstructs the fast path to zero.

Comment: Yes your answer of $2 \pi$ is correct and that is the correct way to calculate. The vector field does not meet the convexity condition in Poincare's Lemma and hence is not conservative. The vector field is curl-free in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ \ $\{(0,0)\}$ which is not a convex set.